# Effective way to store/retrieve objects by incosistent integer index in Swift

Tags: swift, indexing, data-structures

Currently I'm using standard Dictionary [Int: AnyObject] for this. But it's probably not very optimized for that particular integer-key indexing task? I can't use Array since my keys are not consequential and consistent.

Comment: Most performance questions are much better if you do some specific benchmarking for your application to show how bad the current code is and pick a specific target for how good it needs to be.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"—Donald Knuth. Profile your code and  come back with more specific questions when it shows that the indexer is the problem.